# How to use ExifTool by Phil Harvey to adjust all photos in a folder by 1 second for the first file, 2 seconds for second, etc

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I'm a photographer by trade, not a programmer. I'm having trouble understanding the instructions on exiftool.org for how to adjust the time. I want to adjust the first photo up by one second, the second photo up by two seconds, third photo by three seconds, etc...

It's a long story, but all the photos in one particular album all show as if they were captured at the exact same second. Their filenames are in order, but I need their capture time to be different or else Apple Photos will display them in random order.

Below is what I've already got.

```
number=1
capture_date="2022:10:21 15:43:${number} +01:00"

for photo in /Users/zed/Desktop/Louvre/*
    do exiftool -xmp:dateTimeOriginal=$capture_date $photo
    declare -i number+=1
done
```

Comment: In what shell? E.g., `for p in *.png; do echo $number; ((number=$number+1)); done` will inc the number in bash and zsh. The `capture_date` will need to be rebuilt on each iteration; I'd just put it inline w/ the `exiftool` command.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was attempting to write it in bash.

Comment: Do you mean you want to adjust by 1, 2, 3 seconds relative to their existing time? Or you want to adjust them to be 1s later relative to the previous image? If the first two images were taken 10s apart, they'll end up 11s apart with the former and 1s apart with the latter.

Comment: You do not want to loop exiftool.  Instead, you should use exiftool's built in batch capability.  Exiftool's biggest performance hit is the startup time and looping once for each file will extend the processing time tremendously.  See [Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).

Comment: See [this Photo.StackExchange answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/60403/37960)

Answer (score 1):

Using this methodology you'll want something close to this:

```bash
number=1

for p in /Users/Dave/Desktop/*.png; do
  newTime="2022:10:21 15:43:${number}"
  exiftool -AllDates="$newTime" -DateTimeOriginal="$newTime" "$p"
  ((number=$number+1))
done
```

**You'll want to test this with a subset of copies.**

---

`-AllDates` wasn't setting `DateTimeOriginal` for some of my images (from a specific app) so I set both. The filename is quoted because I had images w/ spaces in the filename.

AFAICT exiftool can do this "internally" without needing a shell script at all, e.g., see https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7682.0 and similar, but I don't have a convenient set of photos to test on (and never used exiftool, but may in the future, so thanks :)